# Infinite data scroll in Yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to make infinite scroll for a list in Yii2

So far I have done this, below is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var postParams ={user_id:'1',start:0,end:15};
$('#notificationlist').ready( function () {
    $.ajax({
        'url':'../../../frontend/web/app/notificationlist',
        'type':'post',
        'data': postParams,
        success: function(data)
        {
            var notificationlist = data.notificationlist;
            var notificationcount = data.notification;
            if(notificationcount !== 0){
                $.each(notificationlist, function (index, value) {
                    mood = notificationlist[index].mood_message;
                    output = '<li id='+index+' value='+notificationcount+'>'+index +'</li>'+
                    'first label'+
                    'second label'+
                    'third label'+
                        'forth label'+
                        'fifth label'+
                        'six label';
                    $("#notificationlist").append(output).promise().done();
                });
            }
        }
    });

 });
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    var start = parseInt($('#notificationlist').children().last().attr('id'));
    getresult(start);
    }
});

function getresult(start) {
var postParams ={user_id:'1',start:start,end:7};
$.ajax({
    'url':'../../../frontend/web/app/notificationlist',
    'type':'post',
    'data': postParams,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#loader-icon').show();
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#loader-icon').hide();
    },
    success: function(data){
         var notificationlist = data.notificationlist;
        var notificationcount = data.notification;
        if(notificationcount !== 0){
            $.each(notificationlist, function (index, value) {
                mood = notificationlist[index].mood_message;
                output = '<li id='+index+' value='+notificationcount+'>'+index +'</li>'+
                    'first label'+
                    'second label'+
                    'third label'+
                    'forth label'+
                    'fifth label'+
                    'six label';
                $("#notificationlist").append(output).promise().done();
            });
        }
    },
    error: function(){}
   });
}
```

Now the problem is I don't know how to control the `start` and `end` in the action and in jQuery.

How can I get the starting data and ending data on scroll, for the initial page I can pass the start point and end point, but how to check whether it's the last record on the page and send the start and end point to action?

Comment: Why do you event try to implement your own infinite scroll, when there are tons of solutions that already do just that?

Comment: @Beowulfenator can you please tell me which one? are there any extensions for yii2? and i am trying to implement myself because i am not displaying data from php page directly i am calling action method on page load and getting data via javascript and displaying via javascript

Comment: https://yiigist.com/packages#?search=scroll

Answer (score 0):

Just remember the already loaded items and use this as the "new" start.

```
var alreadyLoadedItems = 0;
$('#notificationlist').ready( function () {
    $.ajax({
        'url':'../../../frontend/web/app/notificationlist',
        'type':'post',
        'data': {user_id:'1',start:alreadyLoadedItems},
        success: function(data)
        {
            var notificationlist = data.notificationlist;
            alreadyLoadedItems += data.notificationCount; // maybe 15 oder something else
            ...
```

Comment: i got that part,but the problem is i dont have any id field which will be in order in my array so i have to use LIMIT in mysql query with start and end limit. Thats where i get confuse, how should i send start and end point to my webservice??

Comment: the start point is send with the post-data (field start) and this is also the offset for the sql-query. the end point can calculated by yourself. for example: if you want 15 elements per call you can do something like that:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM notifications LIMIT 15 OFFSET $alreadyLoadedItems";
See: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp
But be sure that $alreadyLoadedItems is an integer (beware of SQL-Injection)!

Answer (score 0):

**You can use below code for custom infinite scroll**

Code for view

```
   <?php $pjax = \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin();

         echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'options' => ['class' => 'list-view'],
        'itemView' => function ($model) {
            return $this->render('your-view', ['model' => $model]);
        },
        'summary' => false,
        'itemOptions' => [
            'tag' => false //if you want to avoid extra div's
        ],
        'layout' => '{items}<div class="pagination-wrap" style="display:none">{pager}</div>',
        'pager' => [
        ],
    ]);
    \yii\widgets\Pjax::end();
    ?>
```

And here is code for javascript

```
      $(window).load(function () {
            var win = $(window);
            win.scroll(function () {
            if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
            if ($('.pagination .next a:first').attr('href')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: $('.pagination .next a:first').attr('href'),
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    },
                    success: function (text) {
                        var html = $(text);
                        $('#p0').append(html.find('.list-view').html());
                        $('body').find('.pagination').html(html.find('.pagination').html());

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```